# How to observe DOM events in Angular2 using RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use **Angular2 Alpha 46**. I have a list view component as shown below. I want to observe the click events from PREV and NEXT buttons and call a Web API through promise to retrieve the data and update the list.

I don't know whether I should use the **EventEmitter** that comes with **Angular2** or [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) as it is.

Can anyone provide an example?

[image]

Comment: You can either use an `EventEmitter` to emit from the buttons, or you can use [`Observable.fromEvent`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md) *Note that the EventEmitter in the example is Node's, not angular's*

Comment: The example that you provided may work. But is there little more better solution using binding as described [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js/) with angular1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete example but I can sketch a solution for you:

In your template bind to the click event

```html
<button (click)="next()">Next</button>
<button (click)="prev()">Prev</button>
```

In your class (I guess you use Typescript) define next() and prev()

```js
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http';



next() {
   this.http.get("your url")
     .map(res => res.json())  /* if its JSON */
     .subscribe(
        data => this.listdata = data,
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log("Done")
      )
    }

prev() {
  /* like next */
  }
```

You have to import Http and HTTP_BINDINGS.

http.get returns an observable (aka stream) not a promise like in angular 1

There is a video tutorial from Ayden Towfeek that shows how to work with http and observables on youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzmuEhBc3yk)

Comment: That video was helpful. I have some [sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/811). I'm not sure what I have done in that code is correct. I'm trying to wrap my head around the functional and reactive programming.